# How to create an array of slots' indices in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vuejs-slots

I'm creating my own carousel where images are added by <img>. I think that the method of creating carousel component in vue is way more flexible because I want to add inside LightBox component inside my carousel's slots

This is my parent component carousel

```
<template>
    <div class="carousel">
        {{ slides }}
        <slot></slot>
</div>

</template>
<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';
export default{
    data(){
        return{
            Currentslide: 0,
        }
    },
    setup(props, {slots}){
        const slides=ref(slots.default().map((slides) => slides.props.id))
        return{
            slides,
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

This is my child component slide

```
<template>
    <div class="slide">
        <slot/>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

</script>
```

```
<template>
<Carousel>
  <Slide id="1">1243423</Slide>
  <Slide id=2>
    1231
  </Slide>
  <Slide id="3">r445</Slide>
</Carousel>
</template>

<script>
import Carousel from "../../components/Reusable components/Carousel.vue"
import Slide from "../../components/Reusable components/Slide.vue"
export default{
  components:{
    Carousel,
    Slide
  }
}
```

Using the inefficient method in the world, I somehow can create an array of slots' indexes. But this is the worst solution to this problem. So, I want to explore another way of extracting IDs from slots in Vue.js

Comment: This example might helpful https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#scoped-slots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need slots? It can be done much simpler, I guess.

### See the playground

```js
const { createApp } = Vue;

const MyImg = {
  props: ['src'],
  template: '<img :src="src" class="image" />'
}

const MyGallery= {
  components: { MyImg },
  props: ['images'],
  data() {
    return {
        current: 0
        }
  },
  methods: {
    prev() {
      this.current--;
      if (this.current < 0) this.current = this.images.length - 1;
    },
    next() {
      this.current++;
      if (this.current > this.images.length -1) this.current = 0;
    }
  },
  template: '#my-gallery'
}

const App = { 
  components: { MyGallery },
  data() {
    return {
        images: [
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517423568366-8b83523034fd?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=300&q=80',
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1609910063430-33fc20be9f88?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=300&q=80',
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1576138089064-2ca7edab2f49?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=300&q=80',
        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612637306950-fd33786d912e?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=300&q=80'        
        ]
    }
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
label { font-weight: bold; }
.container {
  min-height: 320px;
}
.image {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  position: absolute;  
}

.slide-left-enter-active,
.slide-left-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.slide-left-enter-from {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(150px);
}

.slide-left-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-150px);
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
<div class="container">
  <my-gallery :images="images">
  </my-gallery>
</div>
<p>Pictures &copy Unsplash</p>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="my-gallery">
<button @click="prev()">&lt;</button>&nbsp;Bild {{current + 1}}
  <button @click="next()">&gt;</button>
  <br />
  <transition-group name="slide-left">
    <my-img v-for="(img, index) in images" v-show="current == index" :key="index" :src="img">
    </my-img>
  </transition-group> 
</script>
```